# Running a large number of tasks

Tags: c#, task, stack-overflow

I want to create a large number of tasks n and use in each task i the result I got from task i-1.

I came up with:

```
class TaskTest
{
static int count;
public static void Main()
{
    int n = 1000000;
    var t = Add(n);
    var sum = t.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine("sum is: " + sum);
}

public static Task<int> Add(int step)
{
    Task t = new Task(() => Add(step));
    t.Start();
    if (step == 0)
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    return Task.FromResult(Add(step - 1).Result + 1);

}

static void AddWithLock(int step)
{
    if (step == 0)
        return;
    Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(state => AddWithLock(step - 1), CancellationToken.None);
    t.Wait();

}
  }
```

Using the method Add() works for a small value of n like 1000, but fails with a StackOwerFlowException for n = 1 000 000.

Usin AddWithLock() is not exactly what I want (it does not use the results from other tasks) and while it works for large numbers it is incredibly slow.

So how can I modify the code that it works for numbers such as n = 1 million?

edit:

I tried using TaskCompletionSource but still get StackOverflowException.

```
 public static Task<int> Add2(int step)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    if (step == 0)
        tcs.SetResult(0);

    else
    {
        var r = Add2(step - 1).Result;
        tcs.SetResult(r + 1);
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: You have a recursive function here, `Add` calls `Add` which calls `Add` etc. etc. You can't simply do that a million levels deep.

Comment: I have too many questions for this code to be able to answer anything. Why, for instance, do you create the task `t` and start it? You don't use it. additionally, `Task.FromResult` does not spin up another task so you're in fact just calling `Add` recursively. First of all, come up with a plausible reason for using tasks to begin with, your code can trivially be implemented using a normal loop, which means I'm left wondering why you're involving tasks at all.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here? Or is this just an academic exercise to see how big your stack is?

Comment: To get this to work you need to remove the recursion. The problem isn't with the tasks.

Comment: The goal is as I said: create 1 million tasks and use in each one the result from the previous created task. I am not trying to solve a real world problem. I just want to pass results between a very large number of tasks in a timely manner. The ideea came from here: https://medium.com/@alexyakunin/go-vs-c-part-1-goroutines-vs-async-await-ac909c651c11

Comment: Recursive functions are prone to stack overflow if you let them call themselves often enough.

Comment: @Lasse Task.FromResult does not spin up another task and is calling Add() which spins another task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without using recursion it works good enough. It completes in around 1000 miliseconds on my PC (old i7). No stack exploding.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ManyTasks
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = 1000000;
        Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[n];

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int j = i;
                tasks[i] = new Task<int>(() =>
                {
                    if (j == 0)

                        return 1;

                    var result = tasks[j - 1].Result + 1;
                    return result;
                });
                tasks[i].Start();
                tasks[i].Wait();
            }
        }).Wait();

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(tasks[n - 1].Result);
        Console.WriteLine($"time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds:0.000}ms");


    }
}
}
```